# Interpreting predict() with gamlss() and beta-binomial family=BB

Tags: r, beta-binomial-distribution, gamlss, predict.gamlss

**Note after answer is posted:** *The issue here was actually about formatting the data of the dependent variables in the formula when using (beta-)binomial families. Not about `predict()`. See the answer.*

The output of `predict(...,type="response")`, when I'm using `gamlss(...,family=BB)`, does *not* match the proportion in the data. But when I *exponentiate* the parameter values (instead of using `predict()`), the result *does* match the proportion in the data. What am I not understanding about the output of `predict.gamlss()`?

Here's a minimal example.

First, I generate some data. Each "point" has a total count, N, and a number of successes S ($0 \le S \le N$). N comes from a negative-binomial; S comes from a beta-binomial relative to N.

```r
library("gamlss")
set.seed(47405)
N = as.integer( rnbinom( n=100 , mu=250 , size=500 ) )
S = rBB( n=length(N) , mu=0.8 , sigma=0.1 , bd=N )
theData = data.frame( S=S , N=N )
str(theData)
```

```
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  2 variables:
$ S: int  163 172 245 172 203 168 240 168 179 215 ...
$ N: int  234 249 257 246 225 220 265 198 238 231 ...
```

Here's a boxplot of the data proportions, S/N:

```r
dataProp = sum(theData$S)/sum(theData$N)
boxplot( S/N , data=theData , notch=TRUE , ylab="S/N" )
```

[image: Boxplot of S/N]

*Notice, above, that the overall proportion in the data, S/N, is 0.7917529. In my mind, this value is what `predict(...,type="response")` should (approximately) match.*

But here's what actually is produced:

```r
gamlssInfo = gamlss( cbind( S , N ) ~ 1 ,
                     family = BB , # beta-binomial
                     data = theData ) 
gamlssSumm = summary( gamlssInfo )
gamlssSumm
```

```
              Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.2411631 0.01549786 -15.56105 3.131276e-28
(Intercept) -5.6019584 0.23435204 -23.90403 1.122643e-42
```

Above, the first intercept is mu and the second intercept is sigma.

Finally, the output of `predict()` vs the result of exponentiating mu, compared with the data:

```r
c( "predict()" = predict( gamlssInfo , type="response" )[1] ,
   "exponential()" = exp( gamlssSumm[1,1] ) ,
   "data" = dataProp )
```

```
    predict() exponential()          data 
    0.4399998     0.7857135     0.7917529
```

Notice, above, that the output of `predict()` is way less than the data proportion, but exponentiating the estimate matches the data pretty well. What is `predict()` doing in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I emailed the primary creator of the `gamlss` package, Professor Mikis Stasinopoulos, and he was very kind to provide an extensive explanation and correction to my code.

*The solution is simple: Where I had specified `gamlss( cbind( S , N ) ~ 1 , ...` it should be `gamlss( cbind( S , N-S ) ~ 1 , ...`. That is, the count data should be specified as successes and failures, not as successes and totals. Then the output of `predict.gamlss()` matches the data proportion.*

Professor Stasinopoulos also verified that the output of `gamlss` matches the output of `glm` when using the binomial family (instead of the beta-binomial family).

A giant thank you to Professor Stasinopoulos for clearing up this problem!